# What is the purpose of an actions file in Redux?

Tags: redux, action

I have big problem with understand redux. The worst, I have to use it with vanillia js, but first I have to understand elements of redux. And ok, I understand reducer. There is states and functions. But action? There are only name of possible actions like:

```
const ADD = 'ADD'

export function add(number) {
  return { type: ADD, number}
}
```

And only what it is given to me, that then in switch/case in reducer I have ADD I run some function (from reducer). And I don't understand what this function add should really do. I have functions in reducer, so why I need something that return me type and number? Even if I have a lot of function, action give me only more names, variables and functions and in the end big mess and problem with find something. And redux should give something opposite.

And, I really understand that problem is that I don't understand something and if I understand it redux should give me clear and understandable global storage.

So please, can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are talking about are called "[Action Creators](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions)".

They are not strictly required. It is possible for you to call `dispatch` directly like `dispatch({ type: ADD, number})`.  But most people prefer to use action creators so that they can call `dispatch(add(number))`.  It adds a layer of abstraction such that you can call an action without needing to know how the underlying action object is structured.  And it simplifies things if the action object is complicated.

An "action" in redux is an object which has a `type` property and also has all the other information that the reducer needs to execute the action.  In your case the extra information is just a `number`, but it could be more complex.

This is your action:

```
{ type: ADD, number}
```

An action creator is a function which takes some arguments and uses those arguments to create an action object.

This is your action creator:

```
export function add(number) {
  return { type: ADD, number}
}
```

Yours is very simple, but here's an example to show you how it might be more complicated.

```
export function updateUser(userId, changes) {
    return {
        type: UPDATE_USER,
        payload: {
            id: userId,
            changes,
        },
        meta: {
            timestamp: Date.now(),
        }
    };
}
```

This function doesn't *do* anything except for create the action.  It doesn't update the user -- that is the job of the reducer.

If you are wanting to reduce the amount of boilerplate, you might consider using the [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/basic-tutorial#introducing-createreducer) package, which simplifies things by creating actions automatically based on the reducer.

Comment: ok, thank you very much. It's really helpful for me. I watched a lot of tutorials, and read too, and I was wondering why sometimes there aren't something like action (like I show above), but type and payload are in dispatch. Thank you again